# How to display inputs in Jamsine SpecRunner?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I started using Jasmine to test javascript code and its working fine. But I would like to display inputs to the test suite in specrunner.html.

I tried `HtmlReporter()` and `TrivialReporter()` but no luck.

**SPEC CODE:**

```
checkAddition("TEST_SUITE","Test INPUTS1",getResult(2,3),5);

checkAddition("TEST_SUITE","Test INPUTS2",getResult(3,8),11);

function checkAddition(suite_name,testcase,result,equalto){
  describe(suite_name, function() {
    it(testcase, function() {
        expect(result).toEqual(equalto);
    });
  });
}
```

**JavaScript CODE:**

```
function getResult(input1,input2){
return input1+input2;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :**

[image]

I need to display inputs that looks like expected output (I edited code in browser using firebug to share expected output).

Please help me. Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built reporters won't do this.  You either need to need to hack the innards of those built in reporters to do this (you're on your own with this route), or create your own reports from scratch [(see here for some examples)](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters).

But I find this to be a strange request.  Perhaps there is a cleaner way to achieve your goal, whatever that may be.  Maybe a test suite isn't what you want if you want this info.